# JuJu charms - related to ETSI OSM MANO NFV Deployment

Tags: juju, openstack

I am planning to develop my skills to develop charming skills with the intention of OpenStack deployment and OSM MANO NFV deployment. 
Here I have few queries and hope someone could help me on this.

1. Can anyone kindly provide complete installation guide to deploy OpenStack controller and one compute node using OpenStack. I am confused whether I should install Juju server in the same machine I am planning to install OpenStack or not? Also where should I keep OpenStack package to be used by juju charm ?
2. In ETSI OSM MANO, Juju charms used as VNF Life cycle management scripts? So that I should develop VNF Descriptors as charms. Am I correct on this?
3. If so, Juju server should be used as VNF Manager. Am I correct on this?

Answer (score 2):

An OSM VNFd is a combination of a charm (for VNF operations) and a higher-level description which includes resource and service orchestration descriptions. Think of the OSM descriptor as a package that includes charms but also other metadata.

So yes, charming is a good start for OSM, but you will also want to look at the other parts and understand how they come together.

Comment: Well Mark Thanks for the kind response. I understand that I should have understand on service orchestrator, resource orchestrator. My main concern is how VNF instance is deployed, scaled and managed using charms. 
So that is why I focused on charming. 
Also please be kind enough to advice on deploying 2 -node openstack setup using JuJu charms either on RHEL or Ubuntu (RHEL preferred)